# min $k$ s.t. $|z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n|\geq \frac{1}{k}(|z_1|+|z_2|+\cdots+|z_n|).$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Find the smallest positive real number $k$  such that, given any finite set $z_1,\cdots, z_n$ of complex numbers, all with strictly positive real and imaginary parts, the following inequality holds: $$|z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n|\geq \frac{1}{k}(|z_1|+|z_2|+\cdots+|z_n|).$$

Answer- $\sqrt{2}$

My Attempt:

First, we take $n=2$. Let $z_i=r_ie^{i\theta_i}$ for $i=1, 2$. Then $$|z_1+z_2|^2=|r_1e^{i\theta_1}+r_2e^{i\theta_2}|^2=
r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}.$$ Also $|z_1|+|z_2|=r_1+r_2.$ Therefore, the given inequality holds if
$$r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}\geq \frac{1}{k^2}(r_1+r_2)^2$$ $$\implies (k^2-1)(r_1^2+r_2^2)+r_1r_2(k^2 e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+k^2e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}-2)\geq 0.$$
which holds if $$k^2(e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)})\geq 2$$

I struck at this point. Please help.

Comment: It is not difficult to show that the inequality holds with $k=\sqrt 2$. But I doubt that this is the smallest value if $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @MartinR Actually it holds for $k=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: Yes, that is what I said. It is also easy to see that this is the best possible constant in the case of two numbers. My misunderstanding was that I thought that the question asks for the best constant for a fixed number $n$ (which looks more difficult to me if $n \ge 3$).

Comment: This should also directly follow from minkowski or holder if you rewrite the question in terms of its positive parts.

Comment: Hi, may I know the source of this problem?

Comment: I am sorry.  I encountered this problem a long back and not being able to recall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set $w_k=e^{-i\pi/4}z_k$. Then $w_k=|z_k|e^{i\theta_k}$, where $\theta_k\in [-\pi/4,\pi/4]$, and $\cos\theta_k\ge 1/\sqrt{2}$. Thus
$$
\mathrm{Re}\,w_k\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|w_k|.
$$
Then
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n w_k\right|\ge\sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Re} \,w_k
=\sum_{k=1}^n |w_k|\cos\theta_k 
\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^n |w_k|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^n |z_k|.
$$

Also, $k=\sqrt{2}$ is the smallest.

If $z_1=1+i\varepsilon$ and $z_2=\varepsilon+i$, $\varepsilon>0$, then

$$
|z_1+z_2|=(1+\varepsilon)\sqrt{2}, \qquad
|z_1|+|z_2|=2\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}, \quad
\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_1|+|z_2|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1+\varepsilon}{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}}
$$
and
$$
\inf_{\varepsilon>0}\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_1|+|z_2|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

Comment: I think what you tried to mean is the following $:$ $$\begin{align*} \left |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} z_k \right | & = \left |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} w_k \right | \\ & \geq \text {Re} \left ( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} w_k \right ) \\ & = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \text {Re}\  (w_k) \\ & \gt \frac {1} {\sqrt {2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |w_k| \\ & = \frac {1} {\sqrt {2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |z_k|. \end{align*}$$ Done! BTW very nice answer.+1

Comment: Why you have taken $w_k=e^{-i\pi/4}z_k$. How this idea came into your mind ?

Comment: It is very nice. (+1)